# Simultaneous text highlight and size animation with CSS + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css

I am pretty new to CSS, JavaScript and HTML so this might be a noob questions. Basically, I want the text highlight and size to change simultaneously. I have this so far:

```css
-webkit-transition: font-size 0.5s;
-moz-transition: font-size 0.5s;
-o-transition: font-size 0.5s;
transition: font-size 0.5s;
}


.hl:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0px;
height: 65%;
width: 0;
-webkit-transition: width 0.8s, background 2s, font-size 2s;
transition: width 0.8s, background 2s, font-size 2s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transform-origin: left;
transform-origin: left bottom;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;
box-shadow: 2px 0 0 2px rgba(230,249,0,0.15) inset;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-transform: skewX(-2deg) rotate(-1.5deg) translateY(0);
transform: skewX(-2deg) rotate(-1.5deg) translateY(0);
background: rgba(0, 204, 82,0.85);
box-shadow: 2px 0 0 2px rgba(0,216,255,0.1) inset;
}

.animate .hl:before {
font-size: 40px;
color: #fc0;
background: rgba(255,85,0,0.65);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
This should be <span class="h1"> highlighted</span>
```

The js file looks like this:

```
function highlight_stuff() {
  $('html').toggleClass('animate')
}
```

The text gets highlighted, however it does not change size. I cannot figure out why. Any help is greatly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the new font-size on the `before` pseudo element not the element with the `.hl` class on it. Try this:

```
.animate .hl:before {
  color: #fc0;
  background: rgba(255,85,0,0.65);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.animate .hl {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Ahh. I think I see what you did. Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're toggling a class, appending and then removing it from the `h1`, then the code will look like `class = "h1 animate"` (not the other way around) or `class = h1`. If you correct the animate class then the text will enlarge correctly.

in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/dr0je39m/), I have manually added the `animate` class to display enlarged text (I omitted the javascript as I didn't know where or how you were calling the function, but you get the picture)

hope this helps

Comment: Aha. I understand. Thanks!